# Google Text-to-speech (GoogleTTS) Language Packs for preinstall

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

I would like to build image to preinstall GoogleTTS Language Packs 
without downloading Language Packs by Wifi.

I also found out Language Packs Preinstall Guild from Google release website.
In this document,

```
1. Language packs for English (US) is included in GoogleTTS.apk itself. You don't have to preinstall it.    
2. Language pack files are in zip format. For preinstall, unzip a language pack, and copy extracted files into corresponding installation directory.    
For example, if you want to preinstall German, install unzipped files into /system/tts/google/de-de-x-nfh directory of the device.  
Language pack files include some subfolders - please retain the subfolder structure when unzipping the files in a language pack.    
3. Use these files with GoogleTTS 3.10.10 or later
```

I followed Preinstall Guild, to build image, 
and updated device, when I switch Language
TTS can't play test voice that I prebuild Language.

I listed my integrate stesp:

1. Download GoogleTTS Language Packs from Google release website
   Text-to-Speech(TTS) Language Packs for GoogleTTS3.16+

```
Japanese:ja-jp-r5.zvoice

Chinese (Taiwan):cmn-tw-r5.zvoice

German (Germany):de-de-r5.zvoice

Spanish (Spain):es-es-r5.zvoice
```

2. unzip these Language Packs zip, and copy to source code
3. define a device.mk to copy Language Packs
4. build images
5. updated device by images
6. switch Language to check tts play

I tried to switch device system language to Japanese, 
but TTS play fail.

I also check device /system including these Language Packs

```
device:/ $ cd system/tts/google/
device:/system/tts/google $ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 2019-09-25 12:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2019-09-25 12:02 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2019-09-25 12:02 cmn-tw-x-sxx
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2019-09-25 12:02 de-de-x-nfh
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2019-09-25 12:02 es-es-x-ana
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2019-09-25 12:02 ja-jp-x-htm
```

Log:

```
09-25 17:37:54.396  4166  4166 I TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
09-25 17:37:54.413  4782  4798 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang en-us is name en-US-language (en-us-x-sfg-server)
09-25 17:37:54.414  4166 22396 I TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
09-25 17:37:54.487  4782  4798 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang en-us is name en-US-language (en-us-x-sfg-server)
09-25 17:37:54.643  4782  4802 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang en-us is name en-US-language (en-us-x-sfg-server)
09-25 17:37:54.789  4782  4802 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang en-us is name en-US-language (en-us-x-sfg-server)
09-25 17:37:54.882  4782  4797 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang en-us is name en-US-language (en-us-x-sfg-server)
09-25 17:37:55.157  4782  4797 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang en-us is name en-US-language (en-us-x-sfg-server)
09-25 17:37:55.272  4782 23058 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang en-us is name en-US-language (en-us-x-sfg-server)
09-25 17:38:03.010  4782 23058 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang ja-jp is name ja-JP-language (ja-jp-x-htm-server)
09-25 17:38:03.018  4782  4873 E TTS.ControllerWrapper:         at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onLoadVoice(PG:390)
09-25 17:38:03.091  4782 23058 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang ja-jp is name ja-JP-language (ja-jp-x-htm-server)
09-25 17:38:03.095  4782  4873 E TTS.ControllerWrapper:         at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onLoadVoice(PG:390)
09-25 17:38:03.165  4782  4797 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang ja-jp is name ja-JP-language (ja-jp-x-htm-server)
09-25 17:38:03.168  4782  4873 E TTS.ControllerWrapper:         at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onLoadVoice(PG:390)
09-25 17:38:03.376  4782  4797 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang ja-jp is name ja-JP-language (ja-jp-x-htm-server)
09-25 17:38:03.380  4782  4873 E TTS.ControllerWrapper:         at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onLoadVoice(PG:390)
09-25 17:38:03.459  4782  4797 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang ja-jp is name ja-JP-language (ja-jp-x-htm-server)
09-25 17:38:03.464  4782  4873 E TTS.ControllerWrapper:         at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onLoadVoice(PG:390)
09-25 17:38:10.306  4782  4797 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang ja-jp is name ja-JP-language (ja-jp-x-htm-server)
09-25 17:38:10.310  4782  4873 E TTS.ControllerWrapper:         at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onLoadVoice(PG:390)
09-25 17:38:10.425  4782  4797 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: For default lang ja-jp is name ja-JP-language (ja-jp-x-htm-server)
09-25 17:38:10.429  4782  4873 E TTS.ControllerWrapper:         at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onLoadVoice(PG:390)
09-25 17:38:12.722  4782  4873 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: Synthesis request for locale jpn-JPN and name ja-JP-language
09-25 17:38:12.727  4782  4873 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: TTS dispatch: ja-jp-x-htm-lstm-embedded
09-25 17:38:12.729  4782  4873 E TTS.ControllerWrapper:         at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onSynthesizeText(PG:235)
09-25 17:38:12.731  4782  4873 E TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: Synthesis failure with error status code: -4
09-25 17:38:26.206  4782  4873 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: Synthesis request for locale jpn-JPN and name ja-JP-language
09-25 17:38:26.209  4782  4873 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: TTS dispatch: ja-jp-x-htm-lstm-embedded
09-25 17:38:26.211  4782  4873 E TTS.ControllerWrapper:         at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onSynthesizeText(PG:235)
09-25 17:38:26.213  4782  4873 E TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: Synthesis failure with error status code: -4
09-25 17:38:31.248  4782  4873 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: Synthesis request for locale jpn-JPN and name ja-JP-language
09-25 17:38:31.250  4782  4873 I TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: TTS dispatch: ja-jp-x-htm-lstm-embedded
09-25 17:38:31.251  4782  4873 E TTS.ControllerWrapper:         at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onSynthesizeText(PG:235)
09-25 17:38:31.252  4782  4873 E TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: Synthesis failure with error status code: -4
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

GoogleTTS version: 3.16.6.232892818

Android OS:Pie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out correct path for preinstall GoogleTTS Language Pack

we need to define makefile to copy these Language Packs to system/tts/google 
such as:

Japanese:
system/tts/google/ja-jp